# Why are there multiple Angular language server tabs in my Eclipse console

Tags: angular, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

These days I quite commonly have my PyDev perspective open and do Python programming in Eclipse.  When I run a Python program from the IDE and I go to check the Console for output, I see that not only do I have the output from the Python run, but I count right now 4 Angular language server tabs as well (and none of them are listed as terminated).  One such tab for example has the text

```
[Info]  Angular language server process ID: 75209.
```

Another tab says

```
[Info]  Using @angular/language-service v9.0.0-rc.4 from /Applications/Eclipse JEE.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper_0.5.5.202002262342/language-servers/node_modules/@angular/language-service/bundles/language-service.umd.js
```

How do I get rid of these from appearing when I am doing Python?  Is it simply a property of that plugin?

From eclipse the plugin entry shows:

```
Wild Web Developer  0.8.3.202003111701  org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.feature.feature.group  Eclipse Wild Web Developer project
```

This is a screenshot of what I see in the console window.

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get rid of the Angular consoles by disabling the Angular Language Server in Window > Preferences > Language Servers:

[image]

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  I cannot verify because I don't work on a computer anymore where I experience that problem (doing different sort of work).  My only comment is that on my Mac it is Eclipse > Preferences > Language Servers.

Comment: @demongolem I can verify and this should be marked as correct. Verified on Mac

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it is a bug (in Eclipse itself?) as specified in the plugin's git site.  The Eclipse bug is [Bug 544082 - Close Console when Language Server associated is stopped](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544082) but there may be other related issues raised on the plugin project site.

Perhaps this would be the comparative Wild Web Developer bug [Issue 390](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/390)

Comment: It is not a bug of the Eclipse platform (the Eclipse IDE). Maybe it's a bug of the [VSCode Angular language server](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/pull/584), [Eclipse lsp4e](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=544082) (which is a project of its own), [Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper/issues/390) or a combination of these three. Whatever, Mickael Istria is working on it.

Comment: Not a solution, but maybe helpful: toggle the two pressed buttons that are shown in the screenshot to prevent the language server consoles popping up.