# How to avoid error messages in Eclipse 2020-03 for GWT ui.xml files (Language Server)

Tags: eclipse, gwt, uibinder

In my GWT 2.8 based project Eclipse 2020-03 shows me lots of error message under Markers -> Language Servers
I am sure that these are not errors. For some reason, Eclipse cannot interpret ui.xml files correctly. The application compiles and runs fine:

[image: error messages in eclipse]

My eclipse wide settings for XML validation are as follows:

[image: eclipse settings]

There are not project-specific settings for this

Here is an extract (not the complete source!!!) of one example of a something.ui.xml file. The project contains lots of those files:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder 
    xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder" 
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui"
    xmlns:a="urn:import:com.myapp.client.widgets"
    ui:generateFormat="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat"
    ui:generateKeys="com.google.gwt.i18n.server.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator"
    ui:generateLocales="default" >

<ui:with type="com.myapp.resources.text.CommonMessages" field="msgs" />
<ui:with type="com.myapp.resources.text.SummaryMessages" field="sMsgs" />

<b:Modal closable="true" fade="true" dataBackdrop="STATIC" dataKeyboard="true" 
    b:id="dialog" 
    ui:field="dialog">
    <b:ModalHeader title="{sMsgs.transferOwnership}" />
    <b:ModalBody>
        <g:HTML><ui:text from="{sMsgs.transferOwnershipDescription}"/></g:HTML>

        <b:ListBox 
            ui:field="userListBox"
            multipleSelect="false"
            width="100%"
             />

        <b:Alert type="DANGER" ui:field="participantWarning">
            <b:Icon type="WARNING"/>
            <g:HTML><ui:text from="{sMsgs.transferOwnershipNotParticipantWarning}" /></g:HTML>
        </b:Alert>
    </b:ModalBody>
    <b:ModalFooter>
```

These are the error messages:
[image: error messages]

Mouseover on the error always shows:
[image: individual error message]

although it is declared above:
[...]

```
xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui"
```

[...]

Import: The application compiles and runs fine. So I just want to suppress those error messages (show in error) as they are not really error messages. :-)

These resources might be helpful:

- [Why are there multiple Angular language server tabs in my Eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60992233/why-are-there-multiple-angular-language-server-tabs-in-my-eclipse-console)

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this validation by unchecking the box at Eclipse -> Preferences -> Language Servers -> XML.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (Eclipse 2020-06).

Disabling XML Language Server for XML content type worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. But I would love if you would explain a little bit about this 'Language Server'. I have no idea how it relates to the validation of xml. Just disabling the xml validation has no effect in relation to this error.

Comment: Worked after a restart of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

By "must be declared", it means declared in a Document Type Definition (DTD) or XML Schema, also known as "grammar".

The line you quoted:

```
xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui"
```

It says there's a namespace "b", but this line has no other meaning. It doesn't, for instance, declare which *elements* (like `Alert`) are valid in that namespace.

If you are not worried about validating your XML, and only wish to turn off the error messages, I would suggest you change your options:

> No grammar specified: <strike>Warning</strike> → Ignore

This will stop Eclipse trying to validate the XML against a grammar, but should still show errors for *malformed* XML (tags closed twice etc.). You can configure this option on a per-project basis, if you prefer.

The alternative would be to provide a DTD or Schema and reference it in the XML. You will probably have to write such a grammar yourself unless gwtbootstrap3 provides one (which I don't think it does).

To clear existing validation errors, you may have to [manually delete them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420536/how-do-you-clear-the-validation-errors-in-eclipse).