# Why Eclipse need node.js?

Tags: node.js, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

My Eclipse 2020-06 complained that it need node.js for some editor key features.

I installed node.js along with chocolatey and a lot of packages without any idea and I can't find any information about this on the web. Does anyone know something about this?

**EDIT**

I just found that my html style attribute has a color picker as below now. No clue if it is html editor feature added by node.js and curious that if I can configure (disable) it or not.

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I can't comment so I updated my findings here!

Just as howlger said, I also found there is "Angular language server" messages in my console window that is also discussed in another topic : [Why are there multiple Angular language server tabs in my Eclipse console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60992233/why-are-there-multiple-angular-language-server-tabs-in-my-eclipse-console). I can just ignore it but some of my html with Thymeleaf template scripts reports error is really annoying me.

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Disable Angular Language Servers in Window > Preferences does not solve my issue in EDIT 2.

Another interesting situation is: Before I install node.js, my Eclipse editors LAG very often when I copy/paste or double click some text in the editor. It does not happen after node.js installation. Maybe finding node.js cause the LAG.

Comment: I believe it is used by the Javascript support code which has changed in this release

Comment: Does disabling the two Angular language servers in _Window > Preferences: Language Servers_ fix your issue mentioned in _EDIT 2_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Eclipse Wild Web Developer](https://github.com/eclipse/wildwebdeveloper) which is included in some Eclipse IDE packages provides support for JavaScript, TypeScript, HTML, CSS, etc. via so-called [**language server**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol) and **Node.js is required to execute these language servers**.

Most of the language servers that are included in Wild Web Developer are written in JavaScript (or to be more precise, in TypeScript, which is then translated into JavaScript). In contrast to web browsers, the JavaScript that can be run by Node.js is more standardized and has an additional API, for example to read files.

With the exception of the [XML language server LemMinX](https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx), the language servers that are shipped with Wild Web Developer are developed by non-Eclipse projects not for, or rather not only for Eclipse (the idea of language servers is to support a language, a framework or a format by having only one implementation for multiple IDEs and text editors, preferably in the language to support).

For a list of all language servers contained in your Eclipse IDE, see *Window > **Preferences: Language Servers***.